# Unable to set networking in boot parameters

Tags: boot, networking, system-installation

I'm trying to set up networking at boot/install time.  So far, no luck, the configuration is always through DHCP, as though the ip= line is completely ignored.  This is my latest failed attempt:

```
biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0 ip=192.168.1.125::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:ubuntu-18-04-4:eth0:off
```

Is this wrong, or is any other configuration required, or is the scheme just broken?

The system is netbooting 18.04.4, the latest legacy-server ISO.

Comment: Where are you adding the `ip` argument?  Is there documentation for it?  I'm guessing that it is being used as a kernel boot argument, but if I google for *debian-installer static ip* I see very different suggestions.  Like https://serverfault.com/a/764374 and https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/FAQ#Q:_Why_does_DebianInstaller_always_use_DHCP.3F_I_want_a_static_address.21

Comment: The docs are here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt

Comment: ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:
   <dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>:<ntp0-ip>

  This parameter tells the kernel how to configure IP addresses of devices
  and also how to set up the IP routing table. It was originally called
  `nfsaddrs', but now the boot-time IP configuration works independently of
  NFS, so it was renamed to `ip' and the old name remained as an alias for
  compatibility reasons.
...

Comment: That documentation is for diskless systems using NFS for their root file system.  It requires a kernel with NFS support built-in, and I doubt it applies at all to the installer.  If you are trying to configure the network settings during install then I suggest you review the links I posted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   I became aware of the issue when moving my applications from CentOS where the ip= line works perfectly, and I'm surprised it doesn't work here.

Comment: It looks like CentOS/RedHat uses _dracut_ for initramfs creation, and that supports the `ip` kernel parameter: https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/advanced-install/assembly_kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options/#network-boot-options_kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options .  Ubuntu does not use _dracut_ by default.

Comment: Oh, so that's it!  Thanks for the info!